# SQL XML - 2 Sets Of Separate Data - ORDER BY & RowNumber

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, for-xml, sql-order-by

I have joined together 2 sets of XML data that pull from the SAME Main Table (dbo.Submission).

There is a DATETIME field located in dbo.Submission called [AddedDt], I am selecting the data based on 2 sets of different criteria however I wish to format the returned data with an ORDER BY [AddedDt] as this XML submission has to go in chronological order.

Below is my SELECT statement, I have left the ORDER BY within each query, but this is only ORDERING that relevant query in [AddedDt] Order. I need to add an additional node that has the number of the row, I did in the original data use

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY ( SELECT   sub.AddedDt
                                 ) ) AS "PolicyRecordNumber" ,
```

However this has to appear under the 'Policy' Element of each policy and run sequentially, *How can I achieve this?*

```
SELECT  ( SELECT    sub.Polno AS "Cancellation/PolicyNumber" ,
                sub.Term_date AS "Cancellation/CancellationDate" ,
                sub.PremXIPT AS "Cancellation/ReturnPremium/NetAmount" ,
                sub.PremIPT AS "Cancellation/ReturnPremium/Ipt" ,
                sub.FeeXIPT AS "Cancellation/Fee/NetAmount" ,
                sub.FeeIPT AS "Cancellation/Fee/Ipt"
      FROM      dbo.Submissions sub
      WHERE     sub.[Transaction] = 'Cancellation'
      ORDER BY sub.AddedDt
    FOR
      XML PATH('Policy')  ,
          TYPE
    ) ,
    ( SELECT    sub.Polno AS "PCNewBusiness/PolicyNumber" ,
                sub.[Inception Date] AS "PCNewBusiness/StartDate" ,
                sub.[Renewal Date] AS "PCNewBusiness/StartDate" ,
                sub.PremXIPT AS "PCNewBusiness/Premium/NetAmount" ,
                sub.PremIPT AS "PCNewBusiness/Premium/IPT" ,
                sub.FeeXIPT AS "PCNewBusiness/Fee/NetAmount" ,
                sub.FeeIPT AS "PCNewBusiness/Fee/IPT" ,
                ph.Title AS "PCNewBusiness/Policyholder/PolicyholderType/PrivateIndividual/Name/Title" ,
                ph.Firstname AS "PCNewBusiness/Policyholder/PolicyholderType/PrivateIndividual/Name/FirstNames" ,
                ph.Surname AS "PCNewBusiness/Policyholder/PolicyholderType/PrivateIndividual/Name/LastName" ,
                ph.DateOfBirth AS "PCNewBusiness/Policyholder/PolicyholderType/PrivateIndividual/DateOfBirth" ,
                ph.MaritalStatus AS "PCNewBusiness/Policyholder/PolicyholderType/PrivateIndividual/MaritalStatus" ,
                ph.Sex AS "PCNewBusiness/Policyholder/PolicyholderType/PrivateIndividual/Sex" ,
                ph.Contact AS "PCNewBusiness/Policyholder/Contact" ,
                ph.Addr1 AS "PCNewBusiness/Policyholder/Address/Address1" ,
                ph.Addr2 AS "PCNewBusiness/Policyholder/Address/Address2" ,
                ph.Addr3 AS "PCNewBusiness/Policyholder/Address/Address3" ,
                ph.Addr4 AS "PCNewBusiness/Policyholder/Address/Address4" ,
                ph.Pcode AS "PCNewBusiness/Policyholder/Address/Postcode" ,
                ISNULL(ph.Tel, ph.Tel2) AS "PCNewBusiness/Policyholder/Phone" ,
                ph.Email AS "PCNewBusiness/Policyholder/Email" ,
                cov.Cover AS "PCNewBusiness/Cover/CoverType" ,
                cov.Excess AS "PCNewBusiness/Cover/PolicyExcess" ,
                cov.NCBYears AS "PCNewBusiness/Cover/NoClaimsBonusYears" ,
                cov.NCBOtherVeh AS "PCNewBusiness/Cover/NCBOtherVehicle" ,
                cov.ClassOfUse AS "PCNewBusiness/Cover/Use" ,
                ( SELECT    dri1.RelationshipToPH 'RelationshipToPolicyholder' ,
                            ( SELECT    dri2.Drivertitle 'Title' ,
                                        dri2.FirstName 'FirstNames' ,
                                        dri2.Surname 'LastName'
                              FROM      dbo.Drivers dri2
                              WHERE     dri1.ID = dri2.ID
                                        AND dri1.Driver = dri2.Driver
                            FOR
                              XML PATH('Name') ,
                                  TYPE
                            ) ,
                            dri1.DOB 'DateOfBirth' ,
                            dri1.Licence 'LicenceType' ,
                            dri1.LicenceHeld 'PeriodLicenceHeld' ,
                            ( SELECT    ph1.Addr1 'Address1' ,
                                        ph1.Addr2 'Address2' ,
                                        ph1.Addr3 'Address3' ,
                                        ph1.Addr4 'Address4' ,
                                        ph1.Pcode 'AddressPostcode'
                              FROM      dbo.PolicyHolder ph1
                              WHERE     ph1.ID = ph.ID
                            FOR
                              XML PATH('HomeAddress') ,
                                  TYPE
                            ) ,
                            dri1.PeriodResident 'PeriodResident' ,
                            dri1.VehFreq 'VehicleUseFrequency' ,
                            dri1.OtherVehs 'HasUseOfOtherVehicle' ,
                            ISNULL(dri1.Occupation, [dri1].[2ndOccupation]) 'MainOccupation' ,
                            dri1.[2ndOccupation] 'SecondaryOccupation' ,
                            dri1.RefIns 'MotorInsuranceRefusalDetails' ,
                            dri1.Accconv 'HasCriminalConvictions' ,
                            ( SELECT    'false' 'Removed' ,
                                        TWClaimType 'ClaimType' ,
                                        IncidentDate ,
                                        Amount
                              FROM      dbo.Claims cla1
                              WHERE     cla1.ID = sub.ID
                                        AND cla1.Driver = dri1.Driver
                            FOR
                              XML PATH('DriverClaim') ,
                                  TYPE
                            ) AS "Claims" ,
                            ( SELECT    'false' 'Removed' ,
                                        con1.ConvCode 'ConvictionCode' ,
                                        con1.ConvDate 'ConvictionDate' ,
                                        con1.Amount 'Fine'
                              FROM      dbo.Convictions con1
                              WHERE     con1.ID = sub.ID
                                        AND con1.Driver = dri1.Driver
                            FOR
                              XML PATH('DriverConviction') ,
                                  TYPE
                            ) AS "Convictions" ,
                            ( SELECT    'false' 'Removed' ,
                                        med1.Description ,
                                        med1.AgeDiagnosed ,
                                        med1.Medication ,
                                        med1.[DVLA Notified] 'DvlaNotified' ,
                                        med1.CondNote 'ConditionDeteriorating' ,
                                        med1.LicRest 'LicenceRestricted'
                              FROM      dbo.Medical med1
                              WHERE     med1.ID = sub.ID
                                        AND med1.Driver = dri1.Driver
                            FOR
                              XML PATH('DriverMedicalCondition') ,
                                  TYPE
                            ) AS "MedicalConditions"
                  FROM      dbo.Drivers dri1
                  WHERE     dri1.ID = sub.ID
                FOR
                  XML PATH('Drivers') ,
                      TYPE
                ) AS "PCNewBusiness/Driver" ,
                veh.Make AS "PCNewBusiness/Vehicles/Vehicle/Make" ,
                veh.Model AS "PCNewBusiness/Vehicles/Vehicle/Model" ,
                veh.Reg AS "PCNewBusiness/Vehicles/Vehicle/RegistrationNumber" ,
                veh.Body AS "PCNewBusiness/Vehicles/Vehicle/BodyType" ,
                veh.Parking AS "PCNewBusiness/Vehicles/Vehicle/LocationWhenNotInUse" ,
                ( SELECT    SUM(Mileage) 'AnnualMileage'
                  FROM      dbo.Drivers dri2
                  WHERE     sub.ID = dri2.ID
                ) AS "PCNewBusiness/Vehicles/Vehicle/AnnualMileage" ,
                veh.YearMade AS "PCNewBusiness/Vehicles/Vehicle/YearOfManufacture" ,
                veh.Engine_size AS "PCNewBusiness/Vehicles/Vehicle/EngineSizeCc" ,
                veh.Purchasedate AS "PCNewBusiness/Vehicles/Vehicle/PurchaseDate" ,
                veh.Value AS "PCNewBusiness/Vehicles/Vehicle/PurchasePrice" ,
                veh.Value1 AS "PCNewBusiness/Vehicles/Vehicle/EstimatedValue" ,
                veh.Seats AS "PCNewBusiness/Vehicles/Vehicle/NumberOfSeats" ,
                veh.RightHandDrive AS "PCNewBusiness/Vehicles/Vehicle/RightHandDrive" ,
                veh.Fuel AS "PCNewBusiness/Vehicles/Vehicle/FuelType"
      FROM      dbo.Submissions sub
                LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.PolicyHolder ph ON ph.ID = sub.ID
                LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Cover cov ON cov.ID = sub.ID
                LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Vehicle veh ON veh.ID = sub.ID
      WHERE     sub.[Transaction] = 'New Business'         
      ORDER BY sub.AddedDt           
    FOR
      XML PATH('Policy') ,
          TYPE
    )
FOR     XML PATH('Policies');
```

Comment: Hi! Is this question solved? Do you need further help? Please allow me one hint: If this question is solved, it would be very kind of you, to tick the acceptance check below the (best) answer's vote counter. This will 1) mark this issue as solved 2) make it easier for followers to find the best solution 3) pay points to the answerer and 4) pay points to you. Since you've crossed the 15 points border yourself, you are - additionally - asked to vote on contributions. This is the SO-way to say thank you. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

You can add the running record number in a CTE at first. You posted quite a lot of unnecessary code. The next time please try to reduce your code to the lines needed... Rather add a table declaration and sample data to complete a MCVE...

Here is a *mock-up* of your scenarion

```
DECLARE @YourTbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, AddedDt DATETIME,GroupingValue VARCHAR(100),SomeValue VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO @YourTbl VALUES
 ({ts'2016-01-01 00:00:00'},'A','Value A1')
,({ts'2016-01-02 00:00:00'},'B','Value B1')
,({ts'2016-01-03 00:00:00'},'A','Value A2')
,({ts'2016-01-04 00:00:00'},'A','Value A3')
,({ts'2016-01-05 00:00:00'},'B','Value B3')
,({ts'2016-01-06 00:00:00'},'B','Value B3')
,({ts'2016-01-07 00:00:00'},'A','Value A4');
```

--This is the CTE, which adds the number

```
WITH NumberedCTE AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY AddedDt) AS PolicyRecordNumber
          ,*
    FROM @YourTbl 
)
```

--And this is the grouped XML creation

```
SELECT t1.GroupingValue AS [@ID]
      ,(
        SELECT AddedDt AS [@dt]
              ,SomeValue AS [@val]
              ,PolicyRecordNumber AS [@rn]
        FROM NumberedCTE AS t2
        WHERE t1.GroupingValue=t2.GroupingValue
        ORDER BY PolicyRecordNumber
        FOR XML PATH('Detail'),TYPE
       )
FROM NumberedCTE AS t1
GROUP BY t1.GroupingValue
FOR XML PATH('Group'),ROOT('root')
```

--The result is ordered internally and has got the original record number

```
<root>
  <Group ID="A">
    <Detail dt="2016-01-01T00:00:00" val="Value A1" rn="1" />
    <Detail dt="2016-01-03T00:00:00" val="Value A2" rn="3" />
    <Detail dt="2016-01-04T00:00:00" val="Value A3" rn="4" />
    <Detail dt="2016-01-07T00:00:00" val="Value A4" rn="7" />
  </Group>
  <Group ID="B">
    <Detail dt="2016-01-02T00:00:00" val="Value B1" rn="2" />
    <Detail dt="2016-01-05T00:00:00" val="Value B3" rn="5" />
    <Detail dt="2016-01-06T00:00:00" val="Value B3" rn="6" />
  </Group>
</root>
```